# Restrict TextField from Localization in Flutter

Tags: flutter, localization, flutter-layout

I am using localization with two languages. One is English (LTR) and other is Arabic (RTL). I have a number TextField which I am using for getting phone number. Whenever I change language from English to Arabic, this TextField also changes its orientation. I want to restrict it to LTR regardless of the Locale.

See Locales are directly defined under the MaterialApp widget on the start of widget tree. Whenever I change locale, it changes locale of all the app widgets, which makes sense. But how restrict one TextField for not changing the Locale.

I have searched a lot about it, but couldn't find any solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
```

and wrap you widget with `Directionality(),` widget. This widget have property `textDirection:`
you can use it as you want...

```
textDirection: ui.TextDirection.ltr,
```

or

```
textDirection: ui.TextDirection.rtl,
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a `StatefulWidget` to define a variable `TextDirection direction` and update the direction in `didChangeDependencies` like so if you haven't tried it yet:

```dart
void didChangeDependencies() {
  direction = TextDirection.ltr;
}
```

If this doesn't work, you could try to use a post frame callback and force the direction after the locale is changed. So, when you change the locale, you would want to call this function inside the widget, and the TextField's `textDirection` parameter should no longer be affected by the locale:

```dart
void forceTextDirection() {
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    setState(() => {
      direction = TextDirection.ltr;
    });
  })
}
```